# Centos 6.6 postgresql error: cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, postgresql, centos6

I am running this on centos 6.6

```
PSQL='/usr/bin/psql'

su - postgres "$PSQL" template1 -f 'sql.sql'
```

But starting psql always fails to start

```
Starting postgresql-9.4 service:             [FAILED]
```

and then I get this error

```
/usr/bin/psql: /usr/bin/psql: cannot execute binary file
```

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Please show me an example. I ran `su -c postgres /usr/bin/psql` and i'ts not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
PSQL='/usr/bin/psql'
su - postgres -c "$PSQL template1 -f 'sql.sql'"
```